# How to find users who were disabled during a date range

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I'm trying to get a list of users who were disabled during 2012 and I'm totally lost.  I'm trying to use this script to get the disabled users during the date range, but it says "unexpected token '('"

```
get-aduser -filter {(useraccountcontrol:1.2.840.113556.1.4.803:=2)(modifyTimeStamp -gt (get-date 1/1/2012) -and modifyTimeStamp -lt (get-date 12/31/2012))}
```

What am i doing wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't have an AD at hand right now, so I can't actually test this, but from the looks of it you're mixing LDAP and PowerShell filter criteria. Try something like this instead:

```
$filter = "(useraccountcontrol:1.2.840.113556.1.4.803:=2)"
$start  = Get-Date "1/1/2012"
$end    = Get-Date "12/31/2012"

Get-ADUser -LDAPFilter $filter -Properties "*" | ? {
  $_.modifyTimeStamp -gt $start -and $_.modifyTimeStamp -lt $end
}
```

Comment: Thank you, that seemed to work! Out of curiosity, what is the question mark for?

Comment: `?` is an alias for [`Where-Object`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849715.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

```
#Requires -version 3.0
(Get-ADUser -Filter {Enabled -eq $false} -SearchBase 'ou=users,dc=domain,dc=com' -Property *)..modifytimestamp
```

Hey I never knew about the -Property parameter. Thanks.